# default owner and group for symlink and chown pass-through

Tags: debian, centos, permissions

I have two questions but they are very closely related to each other.

I have a new Debian server by Linode, and my previous server was a CentOS run by Hostgator. I use this command quite frequently for symbolic links:

```
ln -s /home/codebase/classes classes
```

the permissions will look like this on the CentOS server:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 7 root root  4096  Jan 10 classes
```

with permissions being 777 and owner:group being root:root

However the Debian server will show

```
lrwxrwxrwx 7 cpm210 cpm210  4096  Jan 10 classes
```

which is the user:group of the folder it was created in (either way, I'm logged in as root)

question #1, why is there a difference in them and should I accept the cpm210:cpm210 as the default for the Debian server?

question #2: I have a folder, let's say `/var/www/cpm210/public_html` full of files, plus let's say several folder symlinks in there to other locations (usually a codebase library). The codebase folders have other permissions, and so apache can only read those files - exactly what I want. HOWEVER, in the process of moving files around into the public_html folder, I wind up needing to issue this command:

```
chown -R cpm210:cpm210 /var/www/cpm210/public_html/*
```

But I'd like to do this WITHOUT touching the symlinks, only files.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `chown` with `--dereference` as described by [`chown(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chown.1.html). So in your case:

```
chown --dereference -R cpm210:cpm210 /var/www/cpm210/public_html/
```

also the wildcard at the end was unnecessary since you use `-R`.

The opposite would be `--no-dereference` (short `-h`), btw.